# ReactJS: onClick inside .map

Tags: reactjs

I am rendering som buttons with .map but the event onClick is not working for them:

```
render() {
return (
  <div>
    {myArray.map((e)=>(
      <button onClick={console.log("oi")}>
      </button>
    ))}
  </div>
)}
```

When I click any of the buttons, my console doesn't print anything at all. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onClick` is an event that expect a function to handle it.

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
          {myArray.map((e)=>(
            <button onClick={() =>console.log("oi")}>
            </button>
          ))}
       </div>
)}
```